# How to sort with 2 fields merge using query.find()?

Tags: mongoose, discord.js

I was trying to create a leaderboard in Mongoose by merging two `fields` which is the `cash` and the `bank`. I also have `sorting` the cash and bank individually by using:

```js
account.find({})
   .sort([['cash', 'descending']])
   .exec((err, res) => { 
     //Some code here
})
```

Same with the bank:

```js
account.find({})
   .sort([['bank', 'descending']])
   .exec((err, res) => { 
     //Some code here
})
```

But I wanted to do also by merging those two fields and then do sorting them for my `Overall Leaderboard`

What I tried so far is:

```js
account.find({})
   .sort([['cash' + 'bank', 'descending']])
   .exec((err, res) => { 
     //Some code here
})

//Leads to shuffle list
```

also tried:

```js
account.find({})
   .sort([['cash \n bank', 'descending']])
   .exec((err, res) => { 
     //Some code here
}) //Leads to Shuffled list
```

Lastly:

```js
account.find({})
   .sort([['cash', 'bank', 'descending']])
   .exec((err, res) => { 
     //Some code here
})
//Leads to Error: Invalid sort value: [ ' + field + ', ' + value + ' ]
```

Comment: Can you show how you saved your Schema file?

Comment: Its a single field, not in object array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a same code lines before I was creating a leaderboard. Then I figured it out how to merge the two fields in one embed.

You can use `.sort` **inside** of `.exec`.

If you are using a `for loop` You need to put the `.sort` inside of your `for loop`

```js
account.find({})
   .exec((err, res) => { 
     for(i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if(res.length === 0) {
          //Some message for non existing data
       } else if(res.length > 0) {
         const a = await account.find({}).sort([['cash', 'descending']])
         const b = await account.find({}).sort([['bank', 'descending']])

         //Then Calling your sorted fields.
         console.log(`${a[i].cash}`)
         console.log(`${b[i].bank}`)
       }

        //If you are using embed or normal message. Call it after the for loop
        message.channel.send(`${a[i].cash}`)
        embed.addField(`Something here`, `${a[i].cash}`)
        embed.addField(`Something here`, `${b[i].bank}`)
        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
     }
})
```

EDIT:

But if you really need to merge the two fields. You might need to use [aggregate query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html).